# Enter Key Event In Particular Column of DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

[image]

In this DataGridView, if I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key in `DriverID` column, I want to check whether I entered `DriverID` column only. And if I entered `DriverID` column, I want to show one message.

How can I handle this the <kbd>Enter</kbd> keypress event?

My code looks like this:

```
If e.ColumnIndex = 2 Then
    If DGVall.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Driver ID")
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If
```

but it should happen while I am pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key in `DriverId` column

How can I do this?

Comment: please use four spaces before inserting code, makes it more readable... thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You question is a bit fuzzy, but as i understand: you want to force people to fill in the first cell, if not, you want a message...

First of all you need the CellValidating event...

You get something like;

```
    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValidating(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValidating
    If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
        If DataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value Is Nothing AndAlso e.FormattedValue.ToString.Trim = "" Then
            MsgBox("You have to fill this in...")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```